# Could not initialize class io.netty.handler.time out.IdleStateEvent

Tags: ssl, netty, wildfly, cassandra-2.0

We are connecting natively from Wildfly 10 to Cassandra 2.2.2 (both on Centos 7.1, two separate servers, firewall switched off) using `cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9` via **SSL**. Everything seems to work, however the server is continuously generating the following warnings (Wildfly server log):

```
[Server:a] .[33m.[0m.[33m00:06:33,103 WARN  [io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] (cluster1-nio-worker-0) An exception was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateEvent.[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$AllIdleTimeoutTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:433).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m.[0m
[Server:a] .[33m.[0m.[33m00:06:33,435 WARN  [io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] (cluster1-nio-worker-1) An exception was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateEvent.[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$AllIdleTimeoutTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:433).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745).[0m
[Server:a] .[33m.[0m
```

When we were doing exactly the same without SSL, there were no warnings. Other versions of cassandra driver or netty make no change. CQLSH without problem. If we did exactly the same from a normal Java SE application, no problems as well.
So I think it has something in common with Java beans lifecycle, however I cannot find the problem.

Relevant settings in *cassandra.yaml*:

```
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: all
    keystore: /etc/pki/cassandra/keys/.keystore
    keystore_password: password1
    truststore: /etc/pki/cassandra/certs/.truststore
    truststore_password: password1
    # More advanced defaults below:
    # protocol: TLS
    # algorithm: SunX509
    # store_type: JKS
    # cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_12
    require_client_auth: false

# enable or disable client/server encryption.
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: true
    keystore: /etc/pki/cassandra/keys/.keystore
    keystore_password: password1
    require_client_auth: false
    # Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
    truststore: /etc/pki/cassandra/certs/.truststore
    truststore_password: password1
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a project, adding io.netty:netty-all dependency solves it so netty is the root cause.